# Storing coefficients and vectors using the boot package in r

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I am estimating a model of the kind `y= x + s(z)` where `s(z)` is a non parametric function. I want to use bootstrap to get the standard error for the coefficient on `x` and the confidence bands for the function `s(z)`. Basically the result of my estimation gives a coefficient for `x`, therefore a `1x1` object, and a vector `nx1` for `s(z)`. You can do that by using the `gam` package (`gam`) function. For my needs I am using a hand-written function which returns a list named `result`from which I have `result$betax`as the coefficient on `x`, and `result$curve` which stores the vector values (the estimation of `s(z)` gives a set of values corresponding to a curve). I am bootstrapping using the `boot` package as follows

```
result.boot <- boot(data, myfunction, R=3, sim = "parametric", 
                    ran.gen = myfunction.sim, mle = myfunction.mle)
```

I obtain the following error message

```
Error in boot(pdata, myfunction, R = 3, sim = "parametric", 
ran.gen = myfunction.sim, : incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

I guess it should instead gives out a vector of cofficient on x, on which I will compute the standard error, and a matrix `nxn`of `s(z)` values, on which I will compute a s.e. for each row, allowing me to have confidence interval for the `s(z)` curve. I suppose this is related to the fact that the output of my function is given by

```
est <- list("betax" = betax, "curve" = s.z, "residuals"=res)
return(est)
```

How coul I solve this? 
To reproduce the issue it is possible to use the `gam`function

```
y = runif(16, min=0, max=1)
x = runif(16, min=0, max=0.5)
z = runif(16, min=0, max=0.3)
require(gam)
est <- gam(y ~ x + s(z))
```

while I am doing

```
est <- myfunction(y, x, z)
```

Comment: Yes, you're correct that your `myfunction` needs to return a simple vector. (For official documentation of that requirement, see the beginning of the documentation for the `statistic` argument in `?boot`, which states "statistic: A function which when applied to data returns a vector containing the statistic(s) of interest.") So your job is to massage the various elements that you want returned into a single vector.

Comment: basically I could put all the values in a single vector by a command like 
`est <- matrix(c(betax, s.z), ncol=1)`... right?  Then I should write a sort of code which will "automatically" take out the `beta.x` and put them in one vector, the `s(z)` and put them in a matrix `nxn` . Any clue to how to do that in a as fast and as efficient way? Thank you

Comment: Sounds right. When I've used **boot** I'm typically only wanting a very few parameters (on the order of 1-3), and for that, I'd just need `est (c(beta1, beta2, sigma))` or something like that, but it looks like you've got something that works as well. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution implies vectorizing the output of the hand-written function and, therefore, making it compatible with the `boot` procedure which requires results to be stored in a vector.

```
est <- myfunction(y, x, z)
good.output <- matrix(c(betax, s.z), ncol=1)
```

This will let the `boot` function working properly. Then you just extract the corresponding elements of result.boot$t and you compute the statistics you like